# i get 500 error on http://localhost/zftutorial/public

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, ubuntu-10.04, zend-framework

Hi I new in Zend and Lamp,
my software: Zend Framework, Ubuntu10.04,Lamp.

I made my first Zend Project with Zend tool

(according this tutorial 
http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf)

But when i go to  http://localhost/zftutorial/public i get 500 error.

My $ **dir -l** of zftutorial:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2010-06-01 23:54 application
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-06-01 23:54 docs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-06-02 00:23 library
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-06-02 00:00 nbproject
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-06-01 23:54 public
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2010-06-01 23:54 tests
```

my:**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you run this command to know why apache send back error 500 
go and browse the same page  then

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

it might a php error if you had `error_reporting(0)`